# Constructors and aggregates for the same struct?

Tags: c++, c++20

Constructors and aggregates are mutually exclusive for struct. But what in this case is happening here in return statement of MakeOne():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

struct Aggregate  {
    int age;
    std::string name;
};

std::optional<Aggregate> MakeOne() {
    return Aggregate({.name = "Abc"});
};

int main()
{
    auto person = MakeOne();
    
    std::cout << "Age: " << person.value().age << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is it that this?

[Link to run code.](https://onlinegdb.com/8mKgZbcb6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Constructors and aggregates are mutually exclusive

That's not entirely correct. *User-declared* constructors and aggregates mutually exclusive, but implicitly-declared constructors are still possible. In particular these are the implicit copy and move constructors, as well as the default constructor.

> But what in this case is happening here in return for MakeOne():

`Aggregate({.name = "Abc"})` uses the implicitly-defined move constructor of `Aggregate`. A temporary `Aggregate` is materialized from `{.name = "Abc"}` via aggregate initialization to bind the `Aggregate&&` parameter of the move constructor to.

The `std::optional<Aggregate>` in the return type is constructed from the `Aggregate({.name = "Abc"})` and will also use the move constructor internally.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, no copy or move happens, guaranteed copy elision causes a direct initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, the copy elision applies only if the argument is a prvalue expression and a braced-init list is not, see https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.6.1. Instead https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.6.2.1 applies and the move constructor is called.

Comment: A braced init list can be a prvalue.  I had to remove it being an aggregate but you can see no copy happens here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b3f683ad95c5577

Comment: @NathanOliver GCC is not conforming to the standard in this case. A braced-init-list is no an expression and doesn't have a value category. Clang and MSVC do it correctly. (Of course it seems like a missed case where the standard _should_ have specified elision. There are quite a few open CWG issues where seemingly obvious copy elision was missed in the specification.)

Comment: clang gives the same results, cant live link to MSVS but it has the same: https://godbolt.org/z/5c5K6rs8d

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I didn't look at your example carefully. I tested with aggregate initialization, in which case the Clang and MSVC agree that the move/copy constructor is required (https://godbolt.org/z/Gce6h48dd). I think they are still all non-conforming for your example though. I think there was a CWG issue regarding your case. Let me see...

Comment: @user1773 Eliding under as-if is perfectly conforming.  And as there are no observable side effects to creating and destroying a std::string that must be maintained (the SBO size of `std::string` is not specified, nor (as far as I know) is there a demand it be consistent; the compiler is allowed to pretend it is infinitely large under as-if) as-if elision would be legal.  To prove a standard violation you'd have to add an observable side effect to the move.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Of course the as-if rule still applies. But I am talking about elision that is permitted (or required) to affect observable behavior. In NathanOliver's example there is an explicit side effect in the copy constructor and in my example above the program should be ill-formed for using a deleted copy constructor. For both the behavior of the compilers (except MSVC and Clang in the latter) seems non-conforming to me for that reason.

Comment: @NathanOliver: provide standard explicitly as "guaranty copy elision" is since C++17, BTW, gcc/clang disagree with `-fno-elide-constructor` flag [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xrbMenv9x).

Answer (score 1):

The expression `Aggregate({.name = "Abc"})` does two things:

1. First `{.name = "Abc"}` is using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to create an object.
2. Then that object is passed to the compiler-generated [copy-constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of `Aggregate`.